# Remote GitHub repository cannot be reached: generic::invalid_argument in GCP

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-workflows, google-dataform

Hope someone will be able to help me. I built simple pipleline in Dataform repo (connected to GitHub repo) and execute via Workflows in GCP and this morning around 2.37am it is failed. This is the error message i see in Workflows execution logs:

```
"HTTP server responded with error code 400 in step "unhandled_exception", routine "main", line: 28: {"body":{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Remote repository 'https://github.com/xxx/test.git' could not be reached.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

After i manually executing GCP Workflows, it ran successfully.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @sysphp, can you refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/troubleshooting#remote_github_repository_cannot_be_reached_genericinvalid_argument), the subsequent scheduled releases can be successful unless the GitHub or GitLab issues persist.